# Jenkins Group Based Authentication - SAML Google

Tags: jenkins, saml, google-authentication

Have enabled google SAML authentication for Jenkins. I have enabled "Role-based strategy" and created roles for the engineers. All the roles have been assigned to the respective engineers. Now, my question is I wanted to group engineers in the IDP itself. In my case , it's google authentication.  Every time, I need to add the engineers manually in Jenkins to get them access to it. How can we handle the group-based authentication in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

You can [include group memberships](https://support.google.com/a/answer/11143403) in the SAML assertion that's posted to your app/Jenkins:

> using SAML SSO with Google as your IdP, some service provider
> applications will need your user’s group membership information to be
> included in the SAML response.
>
> You can add group membership information on the attribute mapping
> page, available when configuring either pre-integrated SAML apps or a
> custom SAML app.

[Set up instructions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519#:%7E:text=(Optional)%20If%20you%20want%20to%20send%20a%20user%E2%80%99s%20group%20membership%20information%20in%20the%20SAML%20response%2C%20enter%20the%20group%20names%20that%20are%20relevant%20for%20this%20app%20in%20the%20Group%20membership%C2%A0field.)